# PHP SQL Query into a chart.js bar chart - Issue with the array

Tags: php, sql, chart.js

I'm successfully getting the sql data into an array, what I can't seem to work out is how to get that array to show in a chart.js chart. I can get the array into the dataset section but for some reason it isn't rendered? The chart.js code is as-is off the website so excuse the default bits and pieces, I aim to tweak those once I have the data displaying OK.

My code is as follows;

```
<?php

//print_r($_POST);

$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];
$type = $_POST["type"];

//can build sql strings in this ifelse block
if ($type == "both") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM solar_generation WHERE MONTH(timestamp)= $month AND YEAR(timestamp) = $year";
  } elseif ($type == "generation") {
    $sql = "SELECT  timestamp, generation FROM solar_generation WHERE MONTH(timestamp)= $month AND YEAR(timestamp) = $year";
  } else{ 
    $sql = "SELECT timestamp, export FROM solar_generation WHERE MONTH(timestamp)= $month AND YEAR(timestamp) = $year";
  }
echo $sql;

$host = "*******";
$dbname = "solar_generation";
$username = "*******";
$password = "*******";
        
$connection = mysqli_connect(hostname: $host,
                       username: $username,
                       password: $password,
                       database: $dbname);
        
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}  
//Do stuff here
try{
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "$sql");
        echo "Returned rows are: " . $result -> num_rows;
        print("Result of the SELECT query: ");
        print_r($result);
      }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

$dataPoints = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $dataPoints[] = $row;
  }
}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Testing',
        data: [<?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

A page view of the results shows the array inside the dataset section:

```
        data: [[{"timestamp":"2023-07-04 23:59:02","generation":0},{"timestamp":"2023-07-05 23:59:02","generation":26},{"timestamp":"2023-07-06 23:59:02","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-07 23:59:02","generation":43},{"timestamp":"2023-07-08 23:59:02","generation":20},{"timestamp":"2023-07-09 23:59:02","generation":32},{"timestamp":"2023-07-11 23:59:02","generation":22},{"timestamp":"2023-07-12 23:59:02","generation":35},{"timestamp":"2023-07-14 23:59:02","generation":8},{"timestamp":"2023-07-15 23:59:02","generation":33},{"timestamp":"2023-07-16 23:59:02","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-17 16:23:31","generation":35.4},{"timestamp":"2023-07-18 23:00:00","generation":16.2},{"timestamp":"2023-07-19 23:00:00","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-20 23:00:00","generation":23.9},{"timestamp":"2023-07-21 23:00:00","generation":21.7},{"timestamp":"2023-07-22 23:00:02","generation":14.4}]],
```

Can anyone throw any pointers to where this is going wrong?
Thanx

My final solution to this following the advice was:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart" style="height:300px"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Solar - Generated kWh',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
        borderColor: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#FFCC00',
        borderWidth: 1,
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'generation'
        }
    },{
        label: 'Solar Exported kWh',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
        borderColor: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#ED7014',
        borderWidth: 1,
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'export'
        }
    }
  ]
    },
    options: {
        parsing: {
            xAxisKey: 'timestamp',
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *start* seeing your data, you have to do the following:

- drop the square parentheses around data generating php, or use some other method to drop one level of square parentheses (js array literal) in the output - `data` should be an array of objects, not an array of arrays of objects.

```php
data: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
```

- delete the `labels` array
- add `options.parsing.xAxisKey: 'timestamp'`, `options.parsing.yAxisKey: 'generation'`
  to indicate which property should go to the x axis and which one to the y axis [doc link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties).

With these, you'll get something like:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        //labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Testing',
            data: [{"timestamp":"2023-07-04 23:59:02","generation":0},{"timestamp":"2023-07-05 23:59:02","generation":26},{"timestamp":"2023-07-06 23:59:02","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-07 23:59:02","generation":43},{"timestamp":"2023-07-08 23:59:02","generation":20},{"timestamp":"2023-07-09 23:59:02","generation":32},{"timestamp":"2023-07-11 23:59:02","generation":22},{"timestamp":"2023-07-12 23:59:02","generation":35},{"timestamp":"2023-07-14 23:59:02","generation":8},{"timestamp":"2023-07-15 23:59:02","generation":33},{"timestamp":"2023-07-16 23:59:02","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-17 16:23:31","generation":35.4},{"timestamp":"2023-07-18 23:00:00","generation":16.2},{"timestamp":"2023-07-19 23:00:00","generation":28},{"timestamp":"2023-07-20 23:00:00","generation":23.9},{"timestamp":"2023-07-21 23:00:00","generation":21.7},{"timestamp":"2023-07-22 23:00:02","generation":14.4}],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        parsing: {
            xAxisKey: 'timestamp',
            yAxisKey: 'generation'
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" style="height:500px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: This worked perfect and allowed me to expand to do both export and generation - parsing is key here. I ended up using parsing within the dataset section.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you should modify the PHP code to directly assign the $dataPoints array without adding an extra level of nesting. Here's the updated PHP code:

```
$dataPoints = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dataPoints[] = $row['generation']; // Assuming 'generation' is the data point you want to show in the chart
  }
}
```